# Use right click context menu paste in silverlight (4.0) from clipboard to active control

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu

I have a grid with a bunch of textboxes for input.  I wanted to implement Paste functionality.  To do this for one textbox I wrapping it in a grid, adding a contextmenu with Paste item, and in the click event I set that textbox's text to the Clipboard.GetText().

But then I thought perhaps the context menu should be in the larger grid container that holds all the textboxes and then a Paste would set the text in the active textbox.

So my questions:

- does the first way make sense ... I've just started using silverlight 4 and the contextmenu so not sure if this there are other (better) ways of doing this?
- does the 2nd approach sound feasible?
- and if so how do i get the active control?

Answer (score 0):

The following project provides a sample for what you are trying to achieve but it relies on the popupmenu instead of the contextmenu:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com